# Should every question have an answer?

Tags: discussion, answers, comments

Is it necessary for every question to have an answer when a simple comment would suffice?

(Say I have code that does not compile, but someone points out that I have not declared a variable.) The question popped in my mind when I was reading a question which had a "comment" which practically gave the answer, but then subsequently the "answers" also popped up. For example: [Name does not exist even though declared](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29195259/name-does-not-exist-even-though-declared)

Any information would be enlightening.

Comment: Every good question should have an answer. Poor questions should be closed. re `"I have a code that does not compile but someone points out that I have not declared a variable"` -- there's a close reason specifically for that.

Comment: So do you think the question link that I have given should have been closed? Or the people thought better and decided to gain points for answering?

Comment: That one should probably have been closed as a dup since undoubtedly it's been asked many times before.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels Just because a question has no answer, it doesn't mean it is a bad question. It might just be too difficult for all those who have read it and might have otherwise answered. Perhaps someone will come along in the future who has more expertise.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels It's also possible for a question to be unanswerable in the literal sense - e.g. "how do I do X" questions where X is impossible. But a valid answer could nevertheless be "That isn't possible because …" It takes a brave person to say that though; you never know when someone might come up with an imaginative solution that no one had thought of before.

Comment: @IanGoldby: I think you misunderstood what Hovercraft Full Of Eels was saying. He's not saying that a lack of an answer is an indication that a question is low quality. He's saying that if a question is good, then it deserves to be answered. At least, that's how I read it, since that's a more sensible thing to say.

Comment: This question is not appropriate for Stack Overflow.  That's why it got closed.  And closing a question prevents answers from being submitted.  So the way the site works, inappropriate questions should not be answered; and that includes this one.  If a question is both good and appropriate, then obviously, it would be good if it had an answer.

Comment: @pnuts the problem is there is essentially negative initiative on closing as duplicate - it requires time to find (which can be spend on answering some questions) and in often it will not be appreciated (with comments like: "this fake duplicate by some **** uses `foo` variable and I use `bar` - clearly not duplicate"). One can write better answer instead and get upvotes...

Comment: @pnuts, One question is that if upvoting on answers also should be discouraged in a way. Even both user who answered are high scorer, Still they answer this type of question and also get upvoted. If their answer are good to gain so upvotes then obviously question should not be so bad.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels "A good question is never answered. It is not a bolt to be tightened into place but a seed to be planted and to bear more seed toward the hope of greening the landscape of idea." - John Ciardi

Answer (score 51, accepted):

The site is driven on questions **and** answers.  By that, every question that is answerable *should* have an answer with it.

That said, questions which are of poor quality or easily solved due to typos or other simple mistakes aren't the sort of questions that we want here; those should be closed.

If it's answerable enough with a comment, then *more times than not* it should be downvoted as "not useful".

I'll refrain from any action on that particular question, but it really was a matter of not putting the variable in the right place; those sorts of questions aren't useful since scoping is something one learns very early on in their language of choice.

Comment: while I agree, there's is a LARGE discrepancy between what you would find a simple mistake, and what I would find a simple mistake. for work I'm often ask to code in batch files and windev language, which I have 0 ground to work from. When I ask a question I easily do in c# or vb or java, but I cant find any good straight answers, and I finally decide to write it here ... I get really "ticked-off" when it's flag and / or voted down because some people feels its too easy.

Comment: @ThierrySavardSaucier *"I get really "ticked-off" when it's flag and / or voted down because some people feels its too easy"* just don't get ticked off over someone else's views. problem solved.

Comment: Lol, indeed @Kevin B,  sadly it often means the question get sidetrack and I dont get my answer.

Comment: I look at it this way. If I did ask a question that ended up being just a simple mistake such as the example you posted, I would understand why someone would downvote it and just take the rep hit or delete it. It's unfortunate for the OP in this case that the question received an upvoted answer, because now **they can't delete it themselves**. This is why I answer such questions in comments rather than with actual answers.

Comment: By *you*, i mean the OP of this question. :) sorry.

Answer (score 2):

> Is it necessary for every question to have an answer when a simple comment would suffice?

If it's on-topic, **yes**. The comment section is *not* for answers. At all. This is not a chat room or a forum. We have questions, and then their answers. In the answer section. Period.

> (Say I have code that does not compile, but someone points out that I have not declared a variable.)

Then the question has become off-topic, because it's basically a "typo" or "unreproducible problem"<sup>†</sup>. At that point it may not attract an answer, but after a commenter has pointed out the situation (this being more a critique of the question than much else), the question may be downvoted and closed.

<sup><sup>†</sup> There's some leeway here if you genuinely didn't realise you'd made a mistake, but the problem is some trivial syntax issue. I expect this to be the controversial point, especially as it can be difficult to define where the line is drawn.</sup>

Answer (score -5):

The example given indicates that it is quicker to write a brief comment than to provide a complete and tested answer.  The fact that the comment, providing a solution, occurs more quickly than the actual answers suggests that the answerers (probably starting at a similar time to the commentator) were prepared to put in more effort to format their responses as answers.

Whether the question justifies the effort or not is a different subject altogether.

Comment: Yes, it is quicker to write a brief comment. That does not mean it is appropriate to use the comment section for providing answers or even "hints" and "tips".

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Of course. However, there are occasions when asking the OP for further information or making an observation in a comment leads the OP (or another SO user) to the correct answer.  E.g. my comment on [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/29252157/3581917).  I'm usually reluctant to post a formal answer until I'm sure that it is an answer and correct.  Perhaps I've misunderstood the intended use for comments?  In which case, this is being marked as a favourite.  :-)

Comment: Yes, that is precisely what comments are for: requesting clarification. That is not the same as posting an answer or half an answer or a third of an answer in a comment, which is what you did in that example. You were not asking the OP for further information!

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Ok, I should have phrased it as a question.  The OP has now provided enough enformation for me to see the problem and I've submitted a complete answer.